# Add new rows to index without having to reindex everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm wanting to add new rows to my database and I'm wanting to reindex these immediately to search on them via searchkick, However, this is taking a while to reindex all of my table

I haven't had an attempt at this as I can't find the answer on google?

```
      new_events = Event.import(events)
      Event.reindex
      @events = Event.search params[:search], search_options
```

I would prefer if 3 rows were added to add this to the index rather than reindex everything

Comment: you don't have to manually index all(Event.reindex) or individually(new_event.reindex). using active record callbacks data get indexed to elasticsearch automatically. however, there can be few seconds latency. are you worry about that?

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that you need to add just one line of code to your model.

```
searchkick callbacks: :async
```

Did you do it?

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing